# is Lewin's field theory still used in modern psychology? If yes, what are its applications?

Tags: social-psychology, gestalt-psychology

I recently stumbled upon [Kurt Lewin's field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_theory_(psychology)). However, not being very familiar with gestalt psychology, I could not assess whether Lewin's theoretical framework is still used today and if yes, what its applications are.

In other words: Is it still a recognised psychological theory? If yes, what are its application in psychological research and applied psychology? If no: Is it because Lewin's ideas have been proven wrong, because they've been forgotten or because they were never actually accepted within psychology?

Comment: afaik, the Gestalt principle is certainly still used today

Comment: Kurt Lewin's Field Theory is still recognized as a framework. It's applicability depends on your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across Lewin's theory of organisational change a lot. It is often presented in introductory courses on organisational behavior, I/O psychology, and organisational change. It is a three stage theory that talks about unfreezing, making a change, and refreezing.